# Is it possible to retrieve an object in an array that matches my query using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a document like this:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "elements": [
    {
    "type": "configure",
    "time": 3000
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to query for documents with an object in the elements array that have a `type` of `configure` and then also retrieve that specific object in the array so that I can also get the `time` value associated with that element (In this case 3000)?

Comment: Try adding "_source": ["elements"] to just get the elements object in the doc

Comment: That gets me the elements but I want the specific object in the element array that matched so in this case it would { "type": "configure, "time": 3000 }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nested `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) to retrieve details of the nested objects that match for a nested query. Note that `elements` will need to be mapped as a [`nested` datatype field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

Comment: Cool, this accomplishes what I want.